# How can row size error in MYSQL version 5.7 at the time of table creation be solved?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to create a table in my database using the following mysql query. But I am getting some row size error.

```
create table PJC_TXN_XFACE_STAGE_ALL (rowid int AUTO_INCREMENT,error_flag varchar(50),error_message varchar(500),Transaction_Type VARCHAR(100),
Business_Unit_Name VARCHAR(2),
Business_Unit_ID double,
Transaction_Source VARCHAR(240),
Transaction_Source_ID double,
Document VARCHAR(240),
Document_ID double,
Document_Entry VARCHAR(240),
Document_Entry_ID double,
Expenditure_Batch VARCHAR(50),
Batch_Ending_Date VARCHAR(100),
Batch_Description VARCHAR(250),
Expenditure_Item_Date VARCHAR(100),
Person_Number VARCHAR(30),
Person_Name VARCHAR(2000),
Person_ID double,
Human_Resources_Assignment VARCHAR(80),
Human_Resources_Assignment_ID double,
Project_Number VARCHAR(25),
Project_Name VARCHAR(240),
Project_ID double,
Task_Number VARCHAR(100),
Task_Name VARCHAR(255),
Task_ID double,
Expenditure_Type VARCHAR(240),
Expenditure_Type_ID double,
Expenditure_Organization VARCHAR(240),
Expenditure_Organization_ID double,
Quantity double,
Unit_of_Measure VARCHAR(80),
Unit_of_Measure_Code VARCHAR(30),
Work_Type VARCHAR(240),
Work_Type_ID double,
Billable VARCHAR(1),
Capitalizable VARCHAR(1),
Accrual_Batch VARCHAR(1),
Original_Transaction_Reference VARCHAR(120),
Unmatched_Negative_Transaction VARCHAR(1),
Reversed_Original_Transaction VARCHAR(120),
Expenditure_Item_Comment VARCHAR(240),
Accounting_Date VARCHAR(100),
Transaction_Currency_Code VARCHAR(15),
Transaction_Currency VARCHAR(80),
Raw_Cost_in_Transaction_Currency double,
Burdened_Cost_in_Transaction_Currency double,
Raw_Cost_Credit_CCID double,
Raw_Cost_Credit_Account VARCHAR(2000),
Raw_Cost_Debit_CCID double,
Raw_Cost_Debit_Account VARCHAR(2000),
Burdened_Cost_Credit_CCID double,
Burdened_Cost_Credit_Account VARCHAR(2000),
Burdened_Cost_Debit_CCID double,
Burdened_Cost_Debit_Account VARCHAR(2000),
Burden_Cost_Credit_CCID double,
Burden_Cost_Credit_Account VARCHAR(2000),
Burden_Cost_Debit_CCID double,
Burden_Cost_Debit_Account VARCHAR(2000),
Provider_Ledger_Currency_Code VARCHAR(15),
Provider_Ledger_Currency VARCHAR(80),
Raw_Cost_in_Provider_Ledger_Currency double,
Burdened_Cost_in_Provider_Ledger_Currency double,
Provider_Ledger_Conversion_Rate_Type VARCHAR(30),
Provider_Ledger_Conversion_Rate_Date VARCHAR(100),
Provider_Ledger_Conversion_Date_Type VARCHAR(4),
Provider_Ledger_Currency_Conversion_Rate double,
Provider_Ledger_Currency_Conversion_Rounding_Limit double,
Converted VARCHAR(1),
Context_Category VARCHAR(40),
User_Defined_Attribute_1 VARCHAR(150),  
User_Defined_Attribute_2 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_3 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_4 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_5 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_6 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_7 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_8 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_9 VARCHAR(150),
User_Defined_Attribute_10 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_1 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_2 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_3 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_4 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_5 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_6 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_7 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_8 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_9 VARCHAR(150),
Reserved_Attribute_10 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_Category VARCHAR(30),
Attribute_1 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_2 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_3 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_4 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_5 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_6 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_7 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_8 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_9 VARCHAR(150),
Attribute_10 VARCHAR(150),
 PRIMARY KEY(rowid));
```

Error:

> Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Comment: Please don't use all possible tags to get more attention to the question. I will remove everything non-mysql

Comment: You can solve the issue by not creating tables that exceed 65,535 bytes per row. You have numerous `varchar(2000)` and `varchar(150) columns in the table definition. Do you *really* need to store so much text in one table? Check the data types of your columns, because your table will not perform whatsoever with this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Do not splay an array across columns.

For example, you are allowing for 10 attributes.  Have you thought about what to do when you need 11?  Instead of having 10 columns, have a separate table with any number of attributes for each `PJC_TXN_XFACE_STAGE_ALL`.

Ditto for `costs` and maybe other things.

Dates should be in `DATE` datatype, not `VARCHAR(100)`

I see cases of `number`, `name`, `id` -- shouldn't those be in another table, with only the `id` here?

The 8-byte `DOUBLE` is rarely a good datatype for an `ID`.  What do the `IDs` look like?

Say `NOT NULL` where appropriate.

If that does not shrink the schema enough to fit into the limitation; let's see the new `CREATE TABLE` and we can look for more fixes.  (There are other techniques that I have yet to mention.)